# Cannot deploy database volumes configure in "docker compose" file to Azure

Tags: mysql, spring, azure, docker-compose

I cannot get my spring/mysql application, which runs fine locally, into the Azure cloud, using docker-compose

My **docker-compose** file intially looked like this :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - backend
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shapeshop
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - "db-data2:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./SCHEMA.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/SCHEMA.sql"
      - "./TEST_DATA.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/TEST_DATA.sql"
    networks:
      - backend
volumes:
  db-data2:

networks:
  backend:
```

I first set context to my newly created ACI context :

```
docker context use myacicontext
```

then I run :

```
docker compose up
```

and get the following error :

```
cannot use ACI volume, required driver is "azure_file", found ""
```

so reading into this it seems that I need to specifiy a **storage account** and **share name** for my Azure account. So I proceed to do that for my azure account (**shapeshopstorageaccount** and **shapeshopfileshare**).

Heres a screenshot :

[image]

I then proceed to extend the "volumes" defined in my YAML file :

```
volumes:
  db-data2:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: shapeshopfileshare
      storage_account_name: shapeshopstorageaccount
```

*(Update : I tried to repeat these steps before posting the bounty and now have a new error: "The storage account named shapeshopstorageaccount is already taken.". Is this "volumes" actualy trying to recreate shapeshopstorageaccount ?)*

The next error I get is :

> host path ("C:\dev\shape-shop-back-end\SCHEMA.sql") not allowed as
> volume source, you need to reference an Azure File Share defined in
> the 'volumes' section

As a wild guess, I replace all these "docker-entrypoint" in my volumes for mysql with the db-data2 volume, so that it looks like this :

```
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shapeshop
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - "db-data2:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "db-data2:/SCHEMA.sql"
      - "db-data2:/TEST_DATA.sql"
```

This then creates this error :

> containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure
> sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="InvalidContainerImage" Message="The image cannot be empty for
> container 'app-server' in container group 'shape-shop-back-end'."

Now I am starting to get a bit lost. What does all this have to do with images?
My docker-compose should be creating an image and pushing that into a container. I can understand defining the image for mysql because we this is something that is fetched externally, but the app-server image is something that is created locally (I thought), so why do we have to point to an external image? Or is this image definition supposed to declare the image location where the locally built image should be sent to?

Secondly, what does the list of volume entries under the db service mean? Are they pointers to data that the service/container will use?

The first line, I am guess is pointing to a place in the file system where the DB data should be stored: **"db-data2:/var/lib/mysql"**. But the other two lines refer to two files that exist in the original source file system, which I use to setup the database. They also only need to be run once when starting the mysql database. (I am also guessing that **docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** is a pointer to the local system where I executed the docker command)

Basically, how do I get these two files to play into my MySQL container via the file system of my app-server?

Comment: Did you create the azure volumes before running the docker-compose as mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#managing-azure-volumes

Comment: yes....................................

Comment: but as I mentioned I created "shapeshopstorageaccount" with  "shapeshopfileshare", and then I get this error "The storage account named shapeshopstorageaccount is already taken." when I do "docker compose up". Yes these accounts are taken, because I created them!! Azure makes no sense at all.

Comment: I was asking about creating aci volume not storage account and file share...

Comment: ah ok..... let me see

Comment: You are suposing that "build" section of your service will generate an image using ACI integration, but that is not true, at lear for now. Check this link to see the supported features: 

https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-compose-features/

You can see a line that states this: `service.service.build -> Ignored. No image build support on ACI.`

To solve that issue I recommend you to upload your app-server image to Azure Container Registry and then reference it from the docker-compose.yml

Comment: @OliverWatkins  Any luck?